# Detecting Keypress While Outputting to Console Application

Tags: c#

Maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way, but I'd like to be able to output constantly to a console application sort of as a running log, but allow the user to press something like Escape to stop the operations. I've tried a few things involving ReadKey and KeyAvailable but I don't think they quite apply to what I'm looking for. May be a simple issue, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
do {
    while (! Console.KeyAvailable) {
        // your code
    }       
} while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape); //any key that you want to look for);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Console.KeyAvailable`

```
Console.WriteLine("ESC will stop");
do {
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable) {
        // do what you want here
   }       
} while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about your architecture, I would suggest separating the worker (producing the output) and the checking into different threads. This way you don't have to mix your output code and checking for program exit.

This is your worker:

```
class Worker {
    public bool shoudstop {get; set;}
    public bool isrunning {get; set;}

    //....

    public void DoWork() {
        isrunning = true;
        shouldstop = false;
        while (!shouldstop) {
            //do your business logic here
            Console.WriteLine("hello world ...");
        }
        isrunning = false;
    }
    // ...
}
```

And in the main thread, you could just permanently check, whether the escape Key was pressed.

```
//start your worker in a new thread
Worker worker = new Worker();
(new Thread(() => {worker.DoWork(); }).Start();


//Wait, until ESC is pressed
while (true) {
    if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) break;
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}

//Signal the worker thread to stop, and wait until it's finished
worker.shouldstop = true;
while (worker.isrunning) Thread.Sleep(10);
```